# Global TypeORM connection with Jest

Tags: postgresql, jestjs, typeorm

I'm facing some issues using PostgreSQL with TypeORM and Jest. Basically, in each test file, I open the database connection before the tests run, and close it after all tests run. But even though I'm closing the connection I'm receiving a `sorry, too many clients already` error.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to set up a global connection to use in all tests and remove the need to open and close the connection in each file.

I tried to use the Global Setup from jest with the following code:

```js
require('ts-node').register('../tsconfig.json');
require('../src/bootstrap');
const { createConnection, getConnection } = require('typeorm');
const { resolve } = require('path');

const config = require('../src/config/typeorm');

module.exports = async () => {
  await createConnection({
    type: process.env.FINTECH_BACKEND_SQL_DIALECT as 'postgres' | 'mysql',
    host: process.env.FINTECH_BACKEND_SQL_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.FINTECH_BACKEND_SQL_PORT),
    username: process.env.FINTECH_BACKEND_SQL_USER,
    password: process.env.FINTECH_BACKEND_SQL_PASS,
    database: process.env.FINTECH_BACKEND_SQL_DB_NAME,
    synchronize: false,
    entities: [resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'app', 'models', '*')],
  });
};
```

But I don't seem to be able to use this connection in the tests. It just throw an error saying that `Connection "default" was not found`.

Is there a way to setup a global TypeORM connection, or at least to solve the "too many clients" issue?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62470047/typeorm-connection-default-was-not-found-when-connection-is-created-in-jest-gl . You can use runInBand option to avoid "sorry, too many clients already" at least.

Comment: I already use the "runInBand" flag. The only thing that solved for me was increasing the max connections from PostgreSQL. Anyway, I'm moving away from integration tests as much as I can and focusing more in unit testing.