# Typeorm Connection "default" was not found when connection is created in jest globalSetup

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

I'm having a similar problem as in [#5164](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5164) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576307/global-typeorm-connection-with-jest). Consider the following working test code:

```js
// AccountResolver.test.ts
describe('Account entity', () => {
  it('add account', async () => {
    await createConnections()
    const defaultConnection = getConnection('default')

    const actual = await callGraphql(
      `mutation {
        addAccount(options: {
          accountIdentifier: "7csdcd8-8a5f-49c3-ab9a-0198d42dd253"
          name: "Jake, Bob (Braine-l’Alleud) JAM"
          userName: "Bob.Marley@contoso.com"
        }) {
          accountIdentifier
          name
          userName
        }
      }`
    )
    expect(actual.data).toMatchObject({
      data: {
        addAccount: {
          accountIdentifier: '7csdcd8-8a5f-49c3-ab9a-0198d42dd253',
          name: 'Jake, Bob (Braine-l’Alleud) JAM',
          userName: 'Bob.Marley@contoso.com',
        },
      },
    })

    await defaultConnection.query(`DELETE FROM Account`)
    await defaultConnection.close()
  })
})
```

The code to create a connection and close it should be executed before all tests and after all tests are done, that's why we've added it to `globalSetup.ts` and `globalTeardown.ts`:

```js
// globalSetup.ts
require('ts-node/register')
import { createConnections } from 'typeorm'

module.exports = async () => {
  // console.log('jest setup')
  await createConnections()
}
```

```js
// globalTeardown.ts
require('ts-node/register')
import { getConnection } from 'typeorm'

module.exports = async () => {
  const defaultConnection = getConnection('default')
  await defaultConnection.close()
}
```

```js
// AccountResolver.test.ts
describe('Account entity', () => {
  it('add account', async () => {
    const defaultConnection = getConnection('default')
    await defaultConnection.query(`DELETE FROM Account`)

    const actual = await callGraphql(
      `mutation {
        addAccount(options: {
          accountIdentifier: "7csdcd8-8a5f-49c3-ab9a-0198d42dd253"
          name: "Jake, Bob (Braine-l’Alleud) JAM"
          userName: "Bob.Marley@contoso.com"
        }) {
          accountIdentifier
          name
          userName
        }
      }`
    )
    expect(actual.data).toMatchObject({
      data: {
        addAccount: {
          accountIdentifier: '7csdcd8-8a5f-49c3-ab9a-0198d42dd253',
          name: 'Jake, Bob (Braine-l’Alleud) JAM',
          userName: 'Bob.Marley@contoso.com',
        },
      },
    })
  })
})
```

Omitting the line `require('ts-node/register')` from both files throws this error:

> T:\Test\src\it-portal\entity\Account.ts:1
>   import {
>   ^^^^^^
>   SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Keeping the `require` line in throws:

> FAIL  src/resolvers/AccountResolver.test.ts   × add account (31 ms) ●
>   Account entity › add account   ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection
>   "default" was not found.Account entity

#### Version

```
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.44",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
```

#### Config

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  globalSetup: './src/test-utils/config/globalSetup.ts',
  globalTeardown: './src/test-utils/config/globalTeardown.ts',
  setupFiles: ['./src/test-utils/config/setupFiles.ts'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: 'tsconfig.json',
      diagnostics: {
        warnOnly: true,
      },
    },
  },
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
      statements: 80,
    },
  },
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'text', 'clover'],
}
```

Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. As I'm new I tried googling but couldn't really find an answer if this is me not understanding the tool or a bug in the too. Found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1391) with a [PR](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/8751).

It seems like the tests are running in a fully isolated environment where they can't access the connection set up within `globalSetup`.

### Workaround

The only workaround I have found thus far is to add the following code to every test file:

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
  await createConnections()
})

afterAll(async () => {
  const defaultConnection = getConnection('default')
  await defaultConnection.close()
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require('ts-node/register')` shouldn't present in .ts files. They are already processed by TypeScript compiler.

This is not what `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown` are for. They run in Jest parent process and are evaluated once, while each test suite runs in child processes.

This can be achieved by providing a common setup in [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) option:

```
// jest.setup.ts
...
beforeAll(async () => {
  await createConnections()
})

afterAll(async () => {
  const defaultConnection = getConnection('default')
  await defaultConnection.close()
})
```

Since Jest tests run in parallel, this will result in multiple database connections. If this is not desirable because of connection limit, Jest `runInBand` option needs to be used.

A setup for all tests not desirable because not all test suites need database connection, while they will unconditionally take time and occupy database connection pool. In this case jest.setup.ts can be imported directly in tests that use a database instead of `setupFilesAfterEnv`, no need to specify `beforeAll` and `afterAll` in each suite.

Comment: This does indeed work. But as I understand it is executed before each test file and after each test file. Is there a way to have code executed only one before all test files and after all test files and still be able to consume the database connection in the test files?

Comment: Yes, it's executed for each file. As I mentioned, files run in different processes. There are limited ways in which Node processes can exchange data, DB connection object cannot be shared between multiple processes. This isn't specific to Jest. No, there's no way besides making tests run in a single process (e.g. import all test suites in one index.test.js file).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Accepted your answer.

Comment: @EstusFlask is is possible to create a seperate database for each test. I'm trying to use the in memory database from sqlite. But I keep getting error that default already exists

Comment: @Elias See the remark regarding `runInBand`. You can set up dbs in before/afterEach then.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, I'm using `--run-in-band` as a workaround for now, but it is significantly slower than running the tests in parallel. Is there no way to tell typeorm to create a whole new DB for each file?

Comment: @Elias Can't say, don't use typeorm much, the answer was primarily on Jest part. Consider asking a new question that reflects your case.

Comment: @EstusFlask I will do that when (and if...) I have time. Anyway, thank you for your time, have an upvote :)

Comment: @Elias FWIW, `getConnection` can be mocked per test file by means of Jest to replace `'default'` arg with `'default' + uid`, this is a general approach for dbs to allow concurrent tests, in-memory or not. But I'd expect some level of abstraction from ORM that could make this less hacky.